# Load external files in Drools

Tags: drools, kie, drools-guvnor

I'm new to drools and i have setup my application with the kmodule.xml file and the rules files under **/rules** folder. I package the app as a jar and everything works.

My use case though involves new rules being generated at runtime so have new files .gdst being generated. So my question is how can i make my .jar file use those files without them being in the resources folder, but loading them from an external folder at runtime?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kie API to define KieContainer programatically - this includes adding externally loaded rules. On high level it can look like this:

```
KieFileSystem kfs = ...
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/KBase1/ruleSet1.drl", stringContainingAValidDRL )
    .write( "src/main/resources/dtable.xls",
            kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( dtableFileStream ) );
```

See this class which contains unit tests illustrating this end-to-end:
https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/9e335b0ff3b04d30316a9b75fba090784d6967d7/drools-mvel/src/test/java/org/drools/mvel/compiler/builder/KieBuilderTest.java